# Why isn't there armor to protect from spells in the Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter

I am just curious why there is nothing to protect from magical spells other than spells. For example an armor or some shield.

Comment: Don't they put Neville in a bomb suit at some point and toss him around the room?

Comment: @Mazura that sounds a lot like a fanfic.

Comment: Moody did have armour in the movies. It was very obvious, didn't look very comfortable and would probably only help blocking relatively weak curses, so it's not something that would be particularly useful to anyone but aurors, and even then only the paranoid ones.

Comment: The Death Eaters rely on hit-and-run tactics, the Aurors are Policemen, not Army troops...  Even if the Wizarding World *do* have spellproof armour, when would we see anyone who A) had access to it and B) had cause to wear it?

Comment: There is one, it's called the plot armor!

Comment: @Chronocidal, A) The teachers in the school and B) To teach about it. IRL we routinely had lessons in school about emergency services where we would be visited by police officers, firefighters, paramedics and such like and one of the main features of their visits was demonstrations of their equipment - handcuffs, batons and so on. I don't think it is too much of a stretch of the imagination to assume the tutor for Defense Against the Dark Arts would have access to and potentially even keep some basic armor in class if it exists.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Such a thing does exist in-canon

> ‘You wouldn’t believe how many people, even people who work at the Ministry, can’t do a decent Shield Charm,’ said George. ‘Course, they didn’t have you teaching them, Harry.’
>   ‘That’s right … well, we thought Shield Hats were a bit of a laugh. You know, challenge your mate to jinx you while wearing it and watch his face when the jinx just bounces off. But the Ministry bought five hundred for all its support staff! And we’re still getting massive orders!’
>   ‘So we’ve expanded into a range of Shield Cloaks, Shield Gloves …’
>   ‘… I mean, they wouldn’t help much against the Unforgivable Curses, but for minor to moderate hexes or jinxes …’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince : Draco's Detour</sup></sub>

What's baffling is why no-one thought of this before. We can presumably chalk that one up to the relative safety of the Wizarding World for hundreds of years.

---

On a lesser note, people routinely use dragon-hide gloves to handle magical potions, their skin being notoriously resistant to many forms of magic.

> One pair of protective gloves (dragon hide or similar)
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone : Diagon Alley</sup></sub>

Comment: Or, perhaps, nobody who thought of it felt generous enough to give away their secrets. The wizarding world seems less open with powerful secrets than its muggle equivalent.

Comment: "Relative safety of the WW for hundreds of years", yeah, like Voldy's first war, and the Grindelwald War....

Comment: There are quite many instances of wizards not thinking of simple combinations or gadgets for centuries. I think an overall explanation could be, that the minds of wizards simply work different than human minds. How a car works is almost not understandable for an intelligent wizard, but complex spells are quite natural. This just started to change in recent years, when more wizards started to mingle with muggles and a newer generation started to think different and started to invent **to us muggles** seemingly simple applications, which the normal wizard mind just does not think of.

Comment: @Falco there's also a lot fewer wizards than there are muggles. Bear in mind how long the industrial revolution took to come around to; how many things had to be in the right place at the right time, and how so comparatively few people in the muggle world were actually doing the important innovation. When you scale this down to the wizarding world it's quite probable that things would be even slower. It's also worth considering that perhaps as I alluded to there were some previously absent inventions that made such shield clothing feasible.

Comment: @Falco to me, it always looked like most wizards are barely capable of repeating the spells and curses they once learnt from others. Inventing new things happens rarely, perhaps because it requires logic and as Hermione points out in the first book, most Wizards lack logical thinking. If we rank by the capability of inventing new things, the Weasley twins are the most powerful wizards in the storyline, which explains a lot (e.g. they were capable of breaking the Marauder’s Map in their first year).

Comment: Fred and George invented the method for sticking the shield charm on an object. Originally it was a transparent 'force-field' when cast, and even the ministry couldn't work out how Fred and George were doing it.

Comment: "… I mean, they wouldn’t help much against the Unforgivable Curses, but for minor to moderate hexes or jinxes …’" So, useful against the things the good guys use, but useless against the ones the bad guys are using? How many Death Eaters bought one of these?

Comment: @Acccumulation - I'm reasonably sure that most Death Eaters don't throw Unforgiveable curses around all the time (nor that most of them are even capable of doing so). We get quite a skewed idea of how powerful the *average* wizard is, largely because we spend all of our time with the wizard equivalent of aristocracy.

Comment: Apart from dragon hide gloves, Bill also used dragon hide for his boots, although it's never suggested explicitly that he does it for magical protection. "Bill’s  clothes  would  not  have  looked  out  of  place  at  a  rock  concert,  except  that  Harry  recognized  his  boots  to  be  made,  not  of  leather, but of dragon hide. " -- Goblet of Fire, Chapter 5.

Comment: There are also brooms that use anti-jinx varnishes and such, so objectified protection has definitely been a marketed product for some time.

Answer (score 8):

In Chapter Thirty-six of *Order of the Phoenix* Voldemort indeed uses a shield that deflects spells:

> Dumbledore flicked his own wand. The force of the
>   spell that emanated from it was such that Harry,
>   though shielded by his stone guard, felt his hair
>   stand on end as it passed, and this time Voldemort
>   was forced to conjure a shining silver shield out of
>   thin air to deflect it. The spell, whatever it was,
>   caused no visible damage to the shield, though a
>   deep, gonglike note reverberated from it, an oddly
>   chilling sound...

Comment: since this "shield" is obviously conjured it would fall under the spell-VS-spell premise of the question

Comment: Is this a physical metal shield that is imbued with a magical property to deflect spells? Or is this just a spell with a shield-like visual that deflects spells?

Comment: @flowtron The shield is not a spell. It was conjured via a spell.

Comment: @Ellesedil It’s simply described as a silver shield that Voldemort conjured.

Comment: @Alex .. guess why I put it in quotation-marks .. since it is not a *proper* shield.